# vim-go, modules and GoRename

Tags: go, vim

Is there a way I can achieve GoRename to rename all occurences in my whole module?

For example, I have module with go.mod

```golang
module test

go 1.14
```

and 2 packages:
file sub/sub.go

```golang
package sub

import "fmt"

func Sub() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello from sub package")
}

func CallSub() {
    Sub()
}
```

and another:
main/main.go

```golang
package main

import "test/sub"

func main() {
    sub.Sub()
}
```

GoRename correctly renames all references of function Sub in sub package, but not in main. Is it possible to achieve renaming in whole module? Thanks for reply.

*p.s I'm using gopls in my vimrc*

```
let g:go_rename_command = 'gopls'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by running PlugUpdate.